# Drools execute one rule for each rule table inside of decision table excel

Tags: drools

I am looking for a solid solution for exit on the first match rule for each rule table inside the decision table excel,

Currently, there are 2 rule tables in excel,  it is because one field is updated in the first rule table, and the second rule table uses the updated value,

I try below code, but it only fires one rule at the first rule table, not execute any rule from the second rule table, so it doesn't help,

```
kieSession.fireAllRules(1);
```

Comment: Have you tried either using `modify` to change the data in working memory (thus allowing the second set of rules to fire), or separating your tables into different groups (agenda/ruleflow, or even separate kiebases) and firing them separately?

Comment: yes, I use modify update to change the data, but it is not related to my question, and I don't use agenda, not separate kiebases, I was thinking of it but I think there should be a solution for that,

Comment: modify and update are separate things and they work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning all the rules the same `activation-group` and then the correct priority between them with salience or the appropriate mechanisms.

Ref https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#rules-attributes-ref_drl-rules

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fireAllRules(1);`. The `1` means you will only fire one rule. If you want to fire 2 rules, you need to either not pass any value and use `fireAllRules()`, or explicitly call `fireAllRules(2)`. The integer indicates the maximum number of matches (rule hits) allowed -- if you restrict it to 1 you'll only ever have *at most* a single rule trigger; bumping it to 2 means you'll have 0, 1, or 2 hits.

Now for dealing with "first table" and "second table", that's a design question. One option is to load them as separate KieBases and you can easily just fire them sequentially via distinct sessions. Obviously you'll need to copy the modified data from the first session to the inputs of the second session.

Alternatively, you could use the other built-in groupings mechanisms provided by Drools. @tarilabs in their answer suggested [`activation-group`](https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_activation_groups_for_rules), which is a fine choice because it only allows a single rule to fire within that group. Stick all of your "first table" rules under one activation group, and all of your "second table" rules under a second, and then fire them in sequence. There's also [`agenda-groups`](https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_agenda_groups_for_rules) if you want to be a bit looser on the "one rule only" restriction but still need the different groups to run one at a time.